# TABLE_NOT_FOUND on Athena query with SQL Server using Lambda and JDBC

Tags: sql-server, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I'm using federated queries in AWS Athena, querying data on SQL server.

When Connecting to Athena, I am able to visualise, the list of tables and their schema. (show tables & describe [Table Name] are working) But getting error TABLE_NOT_FOUND when running select queries.

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. This was a user rights issue:

1. The SQL Server user account needs to have a user mapping with `db_datareader` and `public` roles on the SQL Server database
2. The SQL Server account used by the Lambda function should be able to read the `SYS.DM_DB_PARTITION_STAT` table.

**SOURCE:** https://github.com/awslabs/aws-athena-query-federation/blob/master/athena-sqlserver/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/athena/connectors/sqlserver/SqlServerMetadataHandler.java